# Equations in fields.

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

[image]

So a) is simple, calculate the squares and cubes mod 7.
However, for b) I know that Z7[x]/(f(x)) if f(x) is irreducible of degree 2 would work, but then how do I solve the equations ?

I assume F7xF7 would also contain 7^2 elements but is it possible to solve the equations in that field ?

How would you go for c) also ? Again F7xF7xF7 has 7^3 elements but can you solve in it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you think $(\mathbb{Z}/(7))^2$ is a field? If so, what is the inverse of $(1,0)$?

Comment: My challenge here is not really how to construct them, for example F7/x^2-3 would work, but how do I solve the equations in that ?

Comment: Could you please give me an example ? I know the definitions but have a hard time picturing it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give full solutions for part (b) only, and hints for parts (c) and (d).  Note that I'll construct the fields as quotients in $\mathbb{F}_7[y]$, since the variable $x$ was used in writing out the polynomials.

**Part (b)**

Let's let $\mathbb{F}_{49} = \mathbb{F}_7[y]/\langle y^2 - 3\rangle$.  Then, the elements of $\mathbb{F}_{49}$ are given by $\mathbb{F}_{49} = \{ay+b| a,b \in \mathbb{F}_7\}$.  Multiplication is subject to the rule $y^2 - 3 = 0$, so $y^2 = 3$.  Thus, the polynomial $x^2 - 3$ factors in $\mathbb{F}_{49}$ as $(x-y)(x+y)$.

Now, let's turn to $x^2-x-1$.  We can re-write this as $(x+3)^2 - 3$, so it has roots $x = 3\pm y$.

**Part (c) (Hint)**
Let $f(y) = y^3 - r$, where $r$ is not a cube $\bmod{7}$, and do the usual construction $\mathbb{F}_{7^3} = \mathbb{F}[y]/\langle f(x)\rangle$

**Part (d) (Hint)**

If $x^2-3$ has roots $\pm\alpha$ in $\mathbb{F}_{7^3}$, then, $\mathbb{F}_{7^3}[x]/\langle x^2-3\rangle$ will have zero divisors (namely, $(\overline{x+\alpha})(\overline{x-\alpha}) = \overline{x^2-3} = \overline{0}$.  Using the Third Isomorphism Theorem, we can turn this into a question about roots of $y^3 - r$ in $\mathbb{F}_7$, which is easier to work with.

Comment: Thanks, but how do you find a good polynomial to construct the field ? Like what made you decide to take y^2-3 ?

Comment: If $f(x)$ is a degree $n$ irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, then $\mathbb{Z}_p[x] /\langle f(x)\rangle$ is the finite field of $p^n$ elements.  Since $3$ is not a square $\bmod 7$, $y^2-3$ is irreducible, so $\mathbb{F}_{7^2} = \mathbb{Z}_p[y]/\langle y^2-3\rangle$ is the field of $7^2 (=49)$ elements.

Comment: Okay great, thanks. And how do I solve x^2-3 and x^2+x-1 in that field ? I don't understand the method.

Comment: Since we quotiented by $y^2-3$, we have that $y^2-3 = 0$, so $y^2 = 3$.  (If you like, $y$ is the 'square root of $3 \bmod 7$'.)  I've used this to find roots for the polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_{49}$.

Comment: And so we're looking for y=(a+bx) such that y^2-3=0 ?

Comment: Yep, exactly right!  Remember that $a$ and $b$ are from $\mathbb{Z}_7$.